# systemd service failed with dependency

Tags: services, systemd, docker

On my ubuntu 16.04 server, I've written two systemd services to start `docker` containers on system reboot. out of them, the initial one loads perfectly. The second service is dependent on the first service which never gets executed.
However, If run 2nd service manually with `sudo  systemctl start swoop.app.service` then It works fine.

here is first script

```
[Unit]
Description=Swoop MongoDb Server container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0

ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose -f /var/www/swoop/docker-compose.yml up -d mongo3 mongo2 mongo1 mongosetup

Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=local.target
```

and the 2nd script is

```
[Unit]
Description=Swoop App Server container
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

Requires=swoop.mongo.service
After=swoop.mongo.service


[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-compose -f /var/www/swoop/docker-compose.yml up -d app

Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=local.target
```

Why It is not able to detect `swoop.mongo.service` service has started or not.

**Update:**

Though service1 docker container's are running after the boot.
Service1 status

```
$ systemctl status swoop.mongo.service 
● swoop.mongo.service - Swoop MongoDb Server container
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/swoop.mongo.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Service2 status

```
$ systemctl status swoop.app.service 
● swoop.app.service - Swoop App Server container
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/swoop.app.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: Have you checked failing service status & journalctl prior to starting it manually? There may be something relevant in there...

Comment: it says `inactive (dead)`  

```● swoop.app.service - Swoop App Server container
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/swoop.app.service; disabled;   vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: if the first service loads and the second depends on the first, then should the `After=swoop.mongo.service` be the only entry under the `[unit]` section ? Remove the `docker.service` entry and see if it goes.

Comment: still the same, It remains inactive.

Comment: surprisingly, the first service status is also `inactive`, though the docker containers which I'm trying to run with 1st service get started automatically after reboot, but not the 2nd one.

Comment: Is `docker-compose` a daemon (that keeps running in the foreground, as systemd expects by default) or is it a one-shot command? In the latter case, you can tell systemd to wait for the end of the command before starting other units, using `Type=oneshot` in the config file (but if the command never terminates, then systemd will never finish booting...).

Comment: yes its oneshot, I've added  `-d` as flag to run it as deamon.

Comment: here is the link that I've followed, http://container-solutions.com/running-docker-containers-with-systemd

Comment: if I start the services manually, both are working well with active status.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out why this wasn't executing.

First I need to enable the services as
`sudo systemctl enable swoop.mongo` && `sudo systemctl enable swoop.app`

Also, I've to change `WantedBy=local.target` to `WantedBy=multi-user.target`.